# MDC-Web Dialog Width

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

Material Design Dialog [guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html) do not address dialog width on tablet or desktop sized viewports.  I read somewhere that increments of 56px should be used but don't know if that's consensus or not.

The HTML inputs I require on my dialog are simply too small for the default sized dialog. It just looks unrefined and I don't want to stretch my input widths too far either to fill the dialog.

Any recommendations on some basic CSS to size the dialog? Maybe a sm, md, lg type of solution? Should I use increments of 56px or?... Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Material Design Dialog guidelines do not address dialog width on tablet or desktop sized viewports.

This is true, **the spec does not describe dialog width for desktops**, so each team does its own implementation. The [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#dialog-section) team uses a fixed width as shown in the example below,

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var dialogButton = document.querySelector('.dialog-button');
    var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog');
    if (! dialog.showModal) {
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    dialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       dialog.showModal();
    });
    dialog.querySelector('button:not([disabled])')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
  }());
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mdl-dialog {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 280px; }
  .mdl-dialog__title {
    padding: 24px 24px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2.5rem; }
  .mdl-dialog__actions {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 24px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
        -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
            flex-direction: row-reverse;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap; }
    .mdl-dialog__actions > * {
      margin-right: 8px;
      height: 36px; }
      .mdl-dialog__actions > *:first-child {
        margin-right: 0; }
    .mdl-dialog__actions--full-width {
      padding: 0 0 8px 0; }
      .mdl-dialog__actions--full-width > * {
        height: 48px;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
            -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
                flex: 0 0 100%;
        padding-right: 16px;
        margin-right: 0;
        text-align: right; }
  .mdl-dialog__content {
    padding: 20px 24px 24px 24px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.54); }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button">Show Dialog</button>

<p>
  Remember that the Dialog component requires the <a href="https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill">Dialog polyfill</a> in order to function.
  It takes advantage of the native dialog element to provide the most robust experience possible.
</p>

<dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
  <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">MDL Dialog</h3>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
    <p>
      This is an example of the Material Design Lite dialog component.
      Please use responsibly.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button" disabled>Disabled action</button>
  </div>
</dialog>
```

while the [MDC-Web](https://material-components-web.appspot.com/dialog.html) team uses a `min-width` of `640px` and a `max-width` of `865px`. [Here is a discussion](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/4412) of the MDL team where they discuss this issue.

> The HTML inputs I require on my dialog are simply too small for the default sized dialog. It just looks unrefined and I don't want to stretch my input widths too far either to fill the dialog.

So, concluding, you could simply implement what suits you best. You could use full width inputs one per line:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var dialogButton = document.querySelector('.dialog-button');
    var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog');
    if (! dialog.showModal) {
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    dialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       dialog.showModal();
    });
    dialog.querySelector('button:not([disabled])')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
  }());
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mdl-dialog {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
    0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
    0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 280px;
}
.mdl-dialog__title {
  padding: 24px 24px 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.mdl-dialog__actions {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 24px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.mdl-dialog__actions > * {
  margin-right: 8px;
  height: 36px;
}
.mdl-dialog__actions > *:first-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width {
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
}
.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width > * {
  height: 48px;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.mdl-dialog__content {
  padding: 20px 24px 24px 24px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

/**/

.mdl-dialog {
  width: fit-content;
}

.mdl-dialog__content .mdl-textfield {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button">Show Dialog</button>

<p>
  Remember that the Dialog component requires the <a href="https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill">Dialog polyfill</a> in order to function. It takes advantage of the native dialog element to provide the most robust experience possible.
</p>

<dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
  <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">MDL Dialog</h3>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
    <form action="#">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button" disabled>Disabled action</button>
  </div>
</dialog>
```

Or you could use multiple inputs per line to fill more space:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var dialogButton = document.querySelector('.dialog-button');
  var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog');
  if (!dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
  }
  dialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.showModal();
  });
  dialog.querySelector('button:not([disabled])')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
}());
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mdl-dialog {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 280px;
}

.mdl-dialog__title {
  padding: 24px 24px 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 24px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions>* {
  margin-right: 8px;
  height: 36px;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions>*:first-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width {
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width>* {
  height: 48px;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.mdl-dialog__content {
  padding: 20px 24px 24px 24px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}


/**/

.mdl-dialog {
  width: fit-content;
  min-width: 600px;
}

.mdl-dialog__content .mdl-textfield {
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button">Show Dialog</button>

<p>
  Remember that the Dialog component requires the <a href="https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill">Dialog polyfill</a> in order to function. It takes advantage of the native dialog element to provide the most robust experience possible.
</p>

<dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
  <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">MDL Dialog</h3>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
    <form action="#">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button" disabled>Disabled action</button>
  </div>
</dialog>
```